# TinyMCE 4 with Internet Explorer 8: Icons are listed vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: internet-explorer-8, tinymce, wysiwyg

I've tried Tiny MCE from 2014-10-30, but in IE8 all icons are shown vertically instead of horizontal. Here is a example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In IE9 it worked out of the box. But for IE8 I had to add this code in the head of my HTML-document:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```